# Crawler facebook in python, partnership

Tags: facebook, web-crawler

I'm a graduate student whose research is complex network. I am working on a project that involves analyzing connections between Facebook users. Is it possible to write a crawler for Facebook based on user's post information?

It is an unusual question, but..
I'm looking for someone who can do it together (if necessary even paid).

Answer (score 0):

Building a Facebook crawler is against the TOS of Facebook:

- https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms (3.2)

> You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our prior permission.

Comment: I am creating a new facebook app, I am in possession of the necessary permits

Comment: You have written permission from Facebook to crawl them?

Comment: my supervisor takes care of administrative notes.He gave me the ok

Comment: I strongly doubt that, or he is ignoring the Facebook TOS. An app will not help you, because with OAuth every user needs to give your app an explicit permit to use his/her data.